# Does proving same answer from different scripture helps the site?

Tags: discussion, answers

Suppose there is a question our main site whose answer is present in multiple scriptures.

A user names A answered the question for scripture X. I can post the same answer, without any change in meaning from scripture Y.  And another user named B can post the same answer using scripture Z.

Is such duplication of answers improves the site in the long run?

(Simple) Example: What is the name of the wife of Nala?

Answer 1(user 1): Damayanti,... From Mahabharata.

Answer 2(user 2): Damayanti, ..... From Devi Bhagavatam..... And so on...

Comment: Same answer as in same content from different scriptures?

Comment: Yeah.............

Comment: As per the example shared, it doesn't make sense to add another answer from different scripture if one is answering already TBH.  But also having answers from different scripture would at least help in validation in some way. I may be wrong!

Comment: If the same user quotes from different scriptures or edits his answer to do so it’ll help to a great extent. Another answer doesn’t make sense

Answer (score 4):

It depends upon the content of question and answers. Let's see some examples (similar to that illustrated in the question)

> Question: What is the story of Damayanti marrying Nala?

It can be possible that the stories found in different scriptures have some variations. So, it would be useful if answers are posted from different scriptures.

> Question: What are the scriptural source for Damayanti being a wife of Nala?

If the question is looking for scriptural references, posting multiple answers citing different scripture is obviously adding values to the site.

> Question: What is the name of the wife of Nala?

This doesn't look like a good question. It looks trivia/quiz type question. If an answer is already posted like "Her name is Damayanati..." citing Mahabharata", then it would not add much value if you post more or less same thing citing different scripture, **however if you can add some more details** (e.g. about Damayanti or story of marriage) apart from what contained by existing answers, **then do it**. It will help the site and visitors.

---

Touching the title of question:

> Does proving same answer from different scripture helps the site?

Well, it will help if the question is looking for proof e.g what mentioned in the second example above.

---

The thing to note down is: If your answer is not adding anything extra or different things from the existing (already posted) answers, then it will not help the site but if your answer contains some extra information or trying to explain the thing with different aspects putting little more efforts, then it will definitely add value to the site.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will be helpful and there is absolutely no harm in providing such answers.

Take for example [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17616/were-women-cursed-with-menstruation/37155#37155) and the various answers provided.

I was probably the first one to answer it and I have used a Smriti scripture.

The other users used Puranas to provide the same details. One used Garuda Purana and another the Bhagavata Purana. Then there are other answers by other users which cite the Vedas.

All these answers mention the same story involving Indra's killing of the Asura and the rest but they cite different scriptures. And, all these answers add to the knowledge of the readers besides enriching the database.

If my answer provides absolutely nothing new when compared to the answers already posted, then my answer can be deleted as "not an answer".
But, when we are using different scriptures we are providing new information.